# Выборка случайный и уникальных значений из БД

Tags: mysql, sql

Предположим есть БД с полями id, word, type. Задача выбрать 10 строк с type = 1. Что-бы они были не по порядку то есть с id A_I 1,2,3..10 А 32,51,42... При этом значения строки не должны повторяться.

Comment: что вы подразумеваете под значением строки? Какое-то поле, где есть дубликаты?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from table
 where type=1
 order by rand()
 limit 10
```

Если надо что бы поле `word` не повторялось в этих записях, то добавьте `group by word` перед `order by`